# Inserting an ampersand in a category name using wp_get_post_terms fails

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am using `wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $myCategory, 'sources', true );` to set the category of a post, using the custom taxonomy 'sources'. One of my existing categories is 'Victoria & Albert Museum' which I have set up from the main Wordpress dashboard without any problems, but when I pass that string as `$myCategory` using the code above it creates a new category simply as 'Victoria'. I have tried escaping the ampersand in several ways but this still hasn't worked. Any thoughts? I don't especially want to force it to 'and' as that's not their correct name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myCategory = str_replace('&','&amp;',$myCategory); // And then your wp_function()...
wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $myCategory, 'sources', true );
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I had tried passing in the category with the ampersand escaped like that and it should work, but your reply prompted me to think in a bit more detail and I now realise that there's something else at play here - the `$myCategory` value is passed in via an AJAX Post request so it is breaking at that point and I need to escape it there. Sorry for not thinking of that one!

I'll mark it as the answer as it is - it was my question that was wrong!